# How can I write a function that returns the smallest value greater than 0 from a list?

Tags: python

I am looking to identify the smallest value greater than 0 from a list but need some help.

Can anyone provide some example code?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def smallest_value_greater_than_0(numbers):
    return min(num for num in numbers if num > 0)
```

As requested in your comment, if you have a dictionary and want to return both the key and value of the item with the smallest value:

```
def smallest_value_greater_than_0(numbers):
    value, key = min((v, k) for k, v in numbers.iteritems() if v > 0)
    return key, value

numbs = dict(A=2, B=3, C=0)
key, value = smallest_value_greater_than_0(numbs)     # key="A", value=2
```

(In Python 3.x, just use `numbers.items()` instead of `numbers.iteritems()`. Also note in Python 3 that all the keys should be of the same type.)

Note that if multiple entries have the same value, this will return the one with the lowest key, using Python's sorting order. For example, if A=1, B=3, C=0, D=1, you will get A=1 back, never D=1. If some keys are numbers and others are strings, or some are uppercase and some are lowercase, you may not get the result you expect, though it will be predictable.

Comment: Wrong order for the `if` and `for` clauses.

Comment: Thanks, helps a lot! As a follow on question, if my list looked like this: numbers = [A: 2, B: 3, c: 0] how could I also return the key associated with the value?

Comment: Well, that's not a list, it's a dictionary. But it's doable; I will add that.

Answer (score 4):

Given initial list called `values`:

```
values = [...]
result = min(value for value in values if value > 0)
```

The resulting value is stored in `result`. Here we use generator expression with filtering [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension) of list comprehensions for memory savings `O(1)` memory in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator:

```
def smallestPositive(lst):
    return min(x for x in lst if x > 0)
```

Comment: @jh313, this solution eats too much memory. You should use generator expressions instead.

Comment: That's not even a loop.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why I wrote loop.  Is this answer wrong?

Comment: @jh314, you are welcome. Now it looks fine, I removed my downvote.